# two foreign keys to the same numeric data type and reference it to two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

it´s possible create two foreign keys to the same type of numerical data in a table and reference it to two tables and I have this exemples in down

create table admin and primary key

```
/* table admin*/
create table admin (id_admin number(10) not null, 
                    email_admin varchar(30) not null, 
                    password_admin varchar(10) not null);
/* primary key */
alter table admin add constraint admin_pk primary key (id_admin);
```

create table user and primary key

```
/* table user*/
create table user (id_user number(10) not null, 
                   email_user varchar(30) not null, 
                   password_user varchar(10) not null);
/* primary key */
alter table user add constraint user_pk primary key (id_user);
```

create table login and primary key and foreign key

```
/* table login*/
create table login(id_login number(10) not null, 
                   id_admin_user_login number(10) not null, 
                   email_login varchar(20) not null, 
                   password_login varchar(10) not null);
/* primary key */
alter table login add constraint login_pk primary key (id_login);

/* foreign key reference to admin*/
alter table login add constraint login_fk_admin foreign key (id_admin_user_login) 
reference admin(id_admin);

 /* foreign key reference to user*/
alter table login add constraint login_fk_user foreign key (id_admin_user_login) 
reference user(id_user);
```

is possible?

Comment: you can have as many FK's pointing at a single field as you want...

Comment: yes, I understand but the problem is the reference from table, if I create login from admin, I have a error that login_fk_user is violate the parent key, so maybe the soltuin is not that I think, but is possible or not?

Comment: then you need to fix your insert. if you're stuffing data into a table with an FK, then you have to make sure there's matching "parent" records in whatever table(s) the FK(s) point at... you can't create orphan records, that'd just defeat the purpose of having FKs in the first place.

Comment: ok, so in that case, what you suppossed?

Comment: You have two `create table user` statements.  The second one is under the `/* table login */` comment so I assume that you mean that to be `create table login`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.  You have three different entities `admin`, `user`, and `login`.  All three of them appear to store the same information-- an email address, a username, and a password (which I hope for basic security is really a password hash).  If there are any relationships between the tables, that violates basic normalization because you'd be storing the same information in multiple places.

Not knowing the business requirements for the entities you're actually trying to model, it is difficult to know precisely what you want.

My first guess is that you have two types of users, admins and regular users, each of which can log in to your application.  Assuming that the attributes of users are pretty consistent regardless of their role (both admins and regular users have email addresses, passwords, etc.) the simplest way to model that would be with a single `login` table with a `login_type` that tells you whether a particular user is an admin or a regular user

```
create table login (
  login_id      integer primary key,
  email         varchar2(255),
  password_hash raw(32),
  login_type    varchar2(1) check( login_type IN ('A', 'U') )
);
```

You can make that a bit more flexible by creating a lookup table for the login types that your `login` table references

```
create table login_type_lkup (
  login_type_code varchar2(1) primary key,
  login_type_desc varchar2(255)
);

create table login (
  login_id        integer primary key,
  email           varchar2(255),
  password_hash   raw(32),
  login_type_code varchar2(1) references login_type_lkup( login_type_code )
);
```

If you want more flexibility, the next step would be to say that logins don't really have a type.  Instead, they have one or more role that has some set of permissions.  You might have an `admin` role and a `regular user` role initially but later want to add a `read only user` role, a `superuser` role, etc.  In that case, you'd have something like

```
create table login (
  login_id        integer primary key,
  email           varchar2(255),
  password_hash   raw(32)
);

create table role (
  role_id integer primary key,
  role_desc varchar2(255)
);

create table permission (
  permission_id integer primary key,
  permission_desc varchar2(255)
);

create table login_role (
  login_id integer references login(login_id), 
  role_id  integer references role(role_id),
  primary key pk_login_role( login_id, role_id )
);

create table role_permission (
  role_id       integer references role(role_id),
  permission_id integer references permission(permission_id),
  primary key pk_role_permission( role_id, permission_id )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Having FK to 2 tables in this case defeats the purpose - a person must be a user and an admin at the same time. Admin or user are in fact roles, so you can have, for instance (oversimplified example, just to illustrate approach. you can find more by searching party-role-relationship model) ,

```
PARTY (party_id (PK), name, ... .);
PARTY_LOGIN(party_login_id(PK), party_id (FK to PARTY), ...);
PARTY_ROLE(party_id (PK,FK), role_id(PK,FK)) ;
```

Comment: I don´t understand this party but I will searching party-role-relationship model, to understand better

Comment: I wanna more suggestion to find a better solution for this question