# ORA-02291: integrity constraint () violated - parent key not found

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-insert

I am trying to create session for `admin` and  `user` both tables are associated  to login table with the same foreign key  - but when I create the seesion for `admin` I'm getting error `PL/SQL: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (login_fk_user) violated - parent key not found`, in my other question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598175/two-foreign-keys-to-the-same-numeric-data-type-and-reference-it-to-two-tables), I did not explain in the best way, but got some ideas on using (party-role-relationship model) and this code below his more related to the question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671878/ora-00933-sql-command-not-properly-ended-when-deleting-two-tables-at-the-same-t)  that has been resolve

create table `admin` and primary key

```
/* table admin*/
create table admin (id_admin number(10) not null, 
                    admin_name varchar(30) not null);
/* primary key */
alter table admin add constraint admin_pk primary key (id_admin);
```

create table `users` and primary key

```
/* table user*/
create table users (id_user number(10) not null, 
                    user_name varchar(30) not null);
/* primary key */
alter table users add constraint user_pk primary key (id_user);
```

create table `login` and primary key and foreign key

```
/* table login*/
create table login(id_login number(10) not null, 
                   id_admin_user_login number(10) not null, 
                   email_login varchar(20) not null, 
                   password_login varchar(10) not null);
/* primary key */
alter table login add constraint login_pk primary key (id_login);

/* foreign key reference to admin*/
alter table login add constraint login_fk_admin foreign key (id_admin_user_login) 
reference admin(id_admin);

 /* foreign key reference to user*/
alter table login add constraint login_fk_user foreign key (id_admin_user_login) 
reference users(id_user);
```

Procedure to create session for admin with table `admin/login`:

```
PROCEDURE create_admin_session( p_name   IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_email  IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_pass   IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_error  OUT NUMBER,
                                p_msg_error OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
p_error := 0;
INSERT ALL
INTO admin (id_admin, admin_name) VALUES(seq_admin.NEXTVAL, p_name)

INTO login(id_login, id_admin_user_login, email_login, pass_login)
VALUES(seq_login.NEXTVAL, seq_admin.CURRVAL, p_email, p_pass)

SELECT * FROM DUAL;
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
p_error     := 1;
p_msg_error := 'Error!'||SQLERRM;
END create_admin_session;
```

Procedure to create session for user with table `users/login`:

```
PROCEDURE create_user_session( p_name   IN VARCHAR2,
                               p_email  IN VARCHAR2,
                               p_pass   IN VARCHAR2,
                               p_error  OUT NUMBER,
                               p_msg_error OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
p_error := 0;
INSERT ALL
INTO users (id_user, user_name) VALUES(seq_user.NEXTVAL, p_name)

INTO login(id_login, id_admin_user_login, email_login, pass_login)
VALUES(seq_login.NEXTVAL, seq_user.CURRVAL, p_email, p_pass)

SELECT * FROM DUAL;
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
p_error     := 1;
p_msg_error := 'Error!'||SQLERRM;
END create_user_session;
```

when I create the admin session, I received a error `ORA-02291: integrity constraint (login_fk_user) violated - parent key not found`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your FKs don't make sense here. `id_admin_user_login` must be present in both the admin and user tables for the insert to work. I don't understand why you have your user and admin tables like that, doesn't look very manageable.

Comment: by my logic I understand that, but apparently I'm wrong

Comment: then the certain is have two different foreign keys for each user and admin and to enter the admin, the foreign key user is null and if the opposite is the foreign key for admin is null, right?

Comment: in this case the I need to do `id_admin_login number(10) null`  and `id_user_login number(10) null `,

Comment: @Mat, following your reasoning, I think I've got and everything works in perfection, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In table login, I add two `id not null` one for user `id_user_login number(10) null` and second for admin `id_admin_login number(10) null`

```
/* table login*/
create table login(id_login number(10) not null, 
                   id_admin_login number(10) null, 
                   id_user_login number(10) null, 
                   email_login varchar(20) not null, 
                   password_login varchar(10) not null);
/* primary key */
alter table login add constraint login_pk primary key (id_login);

/* foreign key reference to admin*/
alter table login add constraint login_fk_admin foreign key (id_admin_login) 
reference admin(id_admin) ON DELETE CASCADE;

 /* foreign key reference to user*/
alter table login add constraint login_fk_user foreign key (id_user_login) 
reference users(id_user) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Procedure to create session for admin with table `admin/login`:

```
PROCEDURE create_admin_session( p_name   IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_email  IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_pass   IN VARCHAR2,
                                p_error  OUT NUMBER,
                                p_msg_error OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
p_error := 0;
INSERT ALL
INTO admin (id_admin, admin_name) VALUES(seq_admin.NEXTVAL, p_name)

INTO login(id_login, id_admin_login, id_user_login, email_login, pass_login)
VALUES(seq_login.NEXTVAL, seq_admin.CURRVAL, NULL, p_email, p_pass)

SELECT * FROM DUAL;
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
p_error     := 1;
p_msg_error := 'Error!'||SQLERRM;
END create_admin_session;
```

Procedure to create session for user with table `users/login`:

```
PROCEDURE create_user_session( p_name   IN VARCHAR2,
                               p_email  IN VARCHAR2,
                               p_pass   IN VARCHAR2,
                               p_error  OUT NUMBER,
                               p_msg_error OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
p_error := 0;
INSERT ALL
INTO users (id_user, user_name) VALUES(seq_user.NEXTVAL, p_name)

INTO login(id_login, id_admin_login, id_user_login, email_login, pass_login)
VALUES(seq_login.NEXTVAL, NULL, seq_user.CURRVAL, p_email, p_pass)

SELECT * FROM DUAL;
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
p_error     := 1;
p_msg_error := 'Error!'||SQLERRM;
END create_user_session;
```

with this resolution, everything works in perfection and if I need to `drop user/login`is worked like I want

Comment: sometimes, a good orientation is necessary so that we can get a sense of logic and thinking about the best way to resolve an question or doubt, Thanks @Mat for your orientation